# Xamarin Databinding and Updating the UI

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

Hi i'm struggling to get the UI to update when a model changes in Xamarin Forms.

I've got a few pages but for simplicity - a ProfilePage which shows the current profile and an Edit Profile Page which has a List containing the profile attributes which when clicked can be edited.

I thought it would be a case of binding the page and controls to a model and then when that model is changed, the UI should reflect that, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

The issue I am having is the UI is not being updated automatically when I make a change to the model. I need to refresh or re-load, so as a workaround I have put the loading code in the OnAppearing method of the page, which clearly isn't correct.

I've got a Profile Class:

```
public class Profile
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string About {get; set;} 
}
```

ProfilePage CodeBehind

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    var p = await getGetDataFromWebservice;
    BindingContext = p;
}

public async void EditPage
{
  EditProfilePage editProfilePage = new EditProfilePage();
  editProfilePage.BindingContext = p;
  Navigation.PushAsync(editProfilePage)
 }
```

ProfilePage XAML

```
<Label Text="{Binding Name, }"></Label>
<Label Text="{Binding About, }"></Label>
```

For my Edit Profile Page, I wasn't sure how to get the profile attributes into a list, so I created a new class to hold this and populated this based on the Profile Items

ProfileItem:

```
public class ProfileItem
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

EditProfilePage CodeBehind:

```
ObservableCollection<ProfileItem> items = new ObservableCollection<ProfileItem>()

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
   p = (Profile)BindingContext;
   items.clear();
   items.Add( (new ProfileItem {Name = "Name", Value=p.Name.ToString() }));
   items.Add( (new ProfileItem {Name = "About", Value = p.About.ToString() }))

    list_Profile_Details.ItemsSource = items;

}
```

EditProfile XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="list_Profile_Details" HeightRequest="500" RowHeight="45">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"  Detail="{Binding Value, }"   />

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

These seems to reflect the updates, but it isn't the correct way to do so, and would appreciate some pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: Read up on `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Answer (score 2):

Solution for your "issue" is to take a look at MVVM pattern. For beginning I will recommend you to take a look at official documentation for "MVVM with Xamarin.Forms", you can find it [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/) and [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm/).

After reading these docs that, you will see that there is a better way to do MVVM and data binding in Xamarin.Forms projects, and first step is to separate logic of your data binding from your code-behind class and to include usage of `ViewModels` in your project.

Best way to update your UI when the state of your model is changed by using `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and `PropertyChangedEventHandler` implementations.

I have couple of blog posts and code examples about MVVM and XF on my blog [here](https://almirvuk.blogspot.ba/), one of my blog posts about simple mvvm is [here](https://almirvuk.blogspot.ba/2016/12/xamarinforms-simple-mvvm-binding-example.html).

Also there are couple of great MVVM Frameworks for Xamarin.Forms that you might want to see later on when you master "plain" MVVM.